# Arrayfire Supported Image Formats

Tags: image, arrayfire

I want to start a little project to identify duplicate images on my hard disk - mainly to try out GPU and Swift. I was looking at Arrayfire and was wondering if it actually is capable of loading RAW images. I read the docu and saw it uses FreeImage but could not figure out what RAW formats are supported. Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

ArrayFire uses FreeImage to load and store images which does support RAW file reading. I have given it a quick try at loading a RAW file from CANON EOS 1DX and it did seem to have loaded properly - although I can't say for certain as I haven't verified the accuracy of image loaded. Given below is the code I tried.

```
array a = af::loadImage("/home/pradeep/Downloads/RAW_CANON_EOS_1DX.CR2", true);
af::Window wnd;
while(!wnd.close())
    wnd.image(normalize(a)); //rescale the channel values to 0-1 range
```

Once you load the image, you can use all the [image processing](http://arrayfire.org/docs/group__image__mat.htm) functions on the loaded af::array.